# hoot upgrade to the pre-release package of mxnet

Tags: pip, mxnet

I want to upgrade to the pre-release package of mxnet [pre](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/releases). Can i do this through `pip`?

I tried `pip` with `--pre --upgrade`. This installed the latest official release. Is there a way where I can upgrade to the pre-release version. i am using mac os

Answer (score 1):

we did not publish the release candidate. You will have to build that [from source](http://mxnet.io/get_started/install.html) yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You can try `pip install mxnet -U --pre`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The poster has clearly stated having tried those options (```-U``` and ```--upgrade``` are synonymous).